# Removing Double Quotes From CSV Export

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following part of code in a SP which exports some results to a CSV. I've tried changing  **ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation** to **ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ","**, but it just doesn't export the file to the path.

```
SET @cmd = 'Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query ''SELECT * FROM '+@tablename+';'' -Database '+@dbname+' -Server "'+@servername+'" -Username '+@username+' -Password '+@password+
        ' | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | select -Skip 1 | Set-Content -Path '+@folderpath+'\'+@filename+' -Encoding UTF8'
SET @cmd = 'powershell.exe -noprofile -command "'+@cmd+'"'
EXEC @return = xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output
    IF @return <> 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'ERROR: '+@cmd
    END
```

How do I get this to export without the double quotes?

Comment: Warning, this looks very open to injection. If you *are* using dynamic SQL **always** safely inject your values.

Comment: As for the problem, the quotes are the a string identifier, not a delimiter. If you use `ConvertTo-Csv -?` you'll notice there's an appropriate switch for controlling the quotes called `QuoteFields`. If you're ever stuck with a command, checking it's manual should always be your first call, and the documentation second.